# calling setState only once inside of useEffect--is there a better method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my react app I use the following pattern quite a bit:

```js
export default function Profile() {
    const [username, setUsername] = React.useState<string | null>(null);

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(`/api/userprofiles?username=myuser`)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data => setUsername(data.username))
        },[])
        
    return(
        <div>
            {username}'s profile
        </div>
    )
}
```

When the page loads, some user data is fetched from the server, and then the page updates with that user data.
One thing I notice is that I only really need to call setUsername() once on load, which makes using state seem kinda excessive. I can't shake the feeling that there must be a better way to do this in react, but I couldn't really find an alternative when googling. Is there a more efficient way to do this without using state? Or is this the generally agreed upon way to load data when it only needs to be done once on page load

Comment: I've done [a write-up](https://github.com/patrickroberts/suspense-service#why-suspense-service) on this very pattern a while back, as well as the library to address it, though I don't recommend using the library since I haven't tested it past React 16. The resources on `Suspense` are what would be helpful to you, and there are some data fetching libraries that have suspense integrations supporting the latest version of React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any external libraries, no - that is *the* way to do it.

It would be possible to remove the state in `Profile` and have it render the username from a prop, but that would require adding the state into the parent component and making the asynchronous request there. State will be needed *somewhere* in the app pertaining to this data.

The logic can be abstracted behind a custom hook. For example, one library has [`useFetch`](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-fetch) where you could do

```
export default function Profile() {
    const { data, error } = useFetch('/api/userprofiles?username=myuser');
    // you can check for errors if desired...

    return(
        <div>
            {data.username}'s profile
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now the state is inside `useFetch` instead of in your components, but it's still there.